# Babel multiple directores into single output directory

Tags: babeljs

I've scouered the documentation for Babel and cannot seem to find an answer, so I turn to the glorious community.

With a directory structure like this:

```
src/
    folder1/
        file1.js
        file2.js
    folder2/
        file3.js
    folder3/
        file4.js
        file5.js
```

I want Babel to transpile all files into a flattened directory:

```
lib/
    file1.js
    file2.js
    file3.js
    file4.js
    file5.js
```

No matter what I try, Babel always inherits the `src/` directory structure. Any ideas?

Comment: You can always do it with `gulp` manually. Why do you want to do this? It also means that all of your import statements won't match up any more and will have to be written with respect to the final build location rather than the source location.

Comment: Because I'm building a library, and i want the library files to be namespaced in the src/ folder but flatteneed in the lib/ folder (which is the only thing i make available via npm when publishing). And I hadn't considered using a manual process to flatten the files post-babel, hell I can probably just use a node script with fs to do it as part of my prepublish, but if babel supports this natively why bother with the extra step?

Comment: It's an extremely uncommon usecase and assumes that all your filenames are unique, which is uncommon. This is not a behavior I've seen in any command-line utility.

Comment: Noted? While I appreciate the judgmental distaste and requisite scorn, I was simply asking if it was possible. If you'd like to further discuss the absurdity of the request rather than potential answers to the question, we can continue it in chat.

Comment: If anyone is also looking for something similar. I wanted to transpile my `server` folder to `dist` folder. That's possible with `babel ./server --out-dir ./dist`. `--out-file` can be also useful if you need more control for each file and you can transpile every file manually in a node js script. I've found an example with the `-out-dir` option [here](https://booker.codes/how-to-build-and-publish-es6-npm-modules-today-with-babel/).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you are using `babel-cli`, you can do this:

```
babel folder1 folder2 folder3 folder4 -d lib
```

which works fine if you have a limited number of folders. It'll output them all flattened.

Answer (score 14):

To expand on samanime's answer, if you're using `babel-cli`, you can simply use a wildcard on your parent folder...

`babel src/** -d lib`